# .Net Core HttpClient returns NotFound 404 on some get calls

Tags: c#, api, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm writing a .NET Core API which collects data by sending API call to external website and save it to database. I have written three methods, Get_Access_Token, Get_Access and Get_Trips first two works file but the third one returns 404 URL not found, Interesting thing that it works on Postman and Swagger UI.
Here is my code

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace KnsPortal.Models.MediRouteCustom
{
    public class MRHttpClient 
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Get and Set the Access Token - Bearer Token
        /// </summary>
        private static AccessToken? _accessToken;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get and Set the list of Access Keys and Funding Sources
        /// </summary>
        private static List<Access.Access>? _accessKey;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the MediRoute Username from config
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _clientId;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get MediRoute Password from config
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _clientSecret;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the GrantType from config, eg. 'Password'
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _grantType;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the API Host URL of MediRoute eg. https://external.medirouteapi.com
        /// </summary>
        private readonly string _apiHost;
        /// <summary>
        /// Set the number of days you want to collect the trips data, Setting 0 will collect the data of current day
        /// </summary>
        private readonly int _nextDaysSpan;
        /// <summary>
        /// Get the instance of HTTPClient
        /// </summary>
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        /// <summary>
        /// Either to included Unscheduled trips or not? 
        /// </summary>
        private readonly bool _includeUnScheduledTrips;
        /// <summary>
        /// Either to include UnPerformed Trips or not?
        /// </summary>
        private readonly bool _includeUnperformedTrips;
        /// <summary>
        /// Either to include Breaks or not?
        /// </summary>
        private readonly bool _includeBreaks;

        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
             .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
             .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
             .Build();
        //readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        static MRHttpClient()
        {
            _accessToken = null!;
        }
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MRHttpClient() { }
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MRHttpClient( HttpClient _client)
        {   
            // Initializing the values on first call
            _httpClient = _client ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_client));
            var config = configuration ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configuration));
            _clientId = config.GetValue<string>("MediRoute:UserName");
            _clientSecret = config.GetValue<string>("MediRoute:Password");
            _grantType = config.GetValue<string>("MediRoute:GrantType");
            _apiHost = config.GetValue<string>("MediRoute:ApiHost");
            _nextDaysSpan = config.GetValue<int>("MediRoute:NextDaySpan");
            _includeUnScheduledTrips = config.GetValue<bool>("MediRoute:IncludeUnScheduledTrips");
            _includeUnperformedTrips = config.GetValue<bool>("MediRoute:IncludeUnPerformedTrips");
            _includeBreaks = config.GetValue<bool>("MediRoute:IncludeBreaks");
        }

        public async Task<List<MediRoute>> GetTrips(List<Access.Access> _acs, AccessToken _tkn)
        {
            var _totalTrips = new List<MediRoute>();
            if (_acs.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _acs.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < _nextDaysSpan + 1; j++)
                    {
                        DateTime _date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(j);
                        // set body parameters required by api 
                        var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", _acs[i].APIKey),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeUnScheduled", _includeUnScheduledTrips.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeUnperformed", _includeUnperformedTrips.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeBreaks", _includeBreaks.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("date", _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        };
                        // initialize a request message
                        //API Host: https://external.mediroutesapi.com
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                        {
                            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                            RequestUri = new Uri(_apiHost + "/api/v1/rides/getRidesByDate"),
                            Headers =
                            {
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer "+_tkn.access_token }
                            },
                            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues)
                        };
                        // sent the api call
                        using var response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);
                        // collect response
                        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        //Deserialize Object from a json format to Object
                        List<MediRoute> _newTrips = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MediRoute>>(responseContent);
                        if (_newTrips.Count > 0)
                        {
                            _totalTrips.AddRange(_newTrips);
                        }
                        // wait for 2 seconds to send next api call
                        Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    }
                    // wait for 2 seconds to send api calls for another trip provider
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                }
                return _totalTrips;
            }
            else return _totalTrips;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me out where I'm doing wrong? I have attached the params snap as well.

[image]

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The *server* returns 404. The client can't change what the server returns. You'll have to check what the server does and why it returns 404 - perhaps it didn't like the parameters? Perhaps some headers are missing?

Comment: But same works in Postman and Swagger. I have just copy pasted the params.

Comment: And yet the *server* disagrees. This means the requests are different. People can't guess what calls are made in each case or why the server returns 404 instead of eg 401. Perhaps the server returns 404 because the token doesn't exist. Use Fiddler or another debugging proxy to see what the actual requests and responses are, and how they differ in each case

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos makes some great points. I'd also like to point out you'll find people will be able to help a lot more if you give us a MCRE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you've essentially copied in most of your application - this isn't useful for us or your. Try and isolate the issue to a small easily reproduceable code block - chances are in doing so, you'll notice the issue yourself. If you don't its exponentially easier to find help

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for pointing to right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Let me post the answer to my own question as how did i figure it out. Query String & Post data are two different set of parameters. Server was expecting Query string and I was sending by FormUrlEncodedContent. If the server explicitly requiring data in query string format, you can't use alternative.

I had to replace

```
var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
                        {
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("api_key", _acs[i].APIKey),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeUnScheduled", _includeUnScheduledTrips.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeUnperformed", _includeUnperformedTrips.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("includeBreaks", _includeBreaks.ToString()),
                            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("date", _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"))
                        };
                        // initialize a request message
                        //API Host: https://external.mediroutesapi.com
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                        {
                            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                            RequestUri = new Uri(_apiHost + "/api/v1/rides/getRidesByDate"),
                            Headers =
                            {
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer "+_tkn.access_token }
                            },
                            Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues)
                        };
```

with

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_apiHost+ "/api/v1/rides/getRidesByDate");
                        var paramValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
                        paramValues.Add("api_key", _acs[i].APIKey);
                        paramValues.Add("includeUnScheduled", _includeUnScheduledTrips.ToString());
                        paramValues.Add("includeUnperformed", _includeUnperformedTrips.ToString());
                        paramValues.Add("includeBreaks", _includeBreaks.ToString());
                        paramValues.Add("date", _date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                        uriBuilder.Query = paramValues.ToString();
                        var url = uriBuilder.Uri.ToString();
                        //
                        // initialize a request message
                        var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                        {
                            Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                            RequestUri = new Uri(uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()),
                            Headers =
                            {
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                                { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer "+_tkn.access_token }
                            }
                        };
```

and it worked.